# Error while deploying docker container to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm new to working with Docker, and I'm trying to deploy an app to heroku but when i visit the app path, it doesn't work. This is what shows in the logs tail

mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied

What should i put in my Dockerfile?

** I previously had another error : 
seteuid: Operation not permitted
I put this in my DockerFile and the error disappeared : `RUN touch /etc/service/cron/down && chmod +x /etc/service/cron/down`

Error i get :

```
See more details with DEBUG=*

2020-05-01T19:03:51.464075+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:52.468555+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:53.477332+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:54.481862+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:55.485818+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:56.489902+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
2020-05-01T19:03:57.494521+00:00 app[web.1]: mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me with a solution..

Comment: It would be better if you can post your dockerfile for reference. Also, were you able to run the same image locally?

Comment: I think the problem is from MYSQL which is requesting access to /dev/xconsole, but how do i cirvumvent this, just stop it from the dockerfile? Even running it locally is a problem